# Get value of data attribute of <li> element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I get value of `data-dial-code` using jQuery?

```
<ul class="country-list>
    <li class="country preferred active" data-dial-code="1" data-country-code="us">...</li>
</ul>

<ul class="country-list>
    <li class="country preferred active" data-dial-code="48" data-country-code="pl">...</li>
</ul>
```

I can get this element like this bacause I have to list with the same class but I need the second one:

`$('.country-list .active')[1]`

Comment: Here is an introduction [attr()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below two ways to read data attribute value of second li only

BTW: you have missed closing double quote for class of ul -- `<ul class="country-list">`, so correct it in your source code

```js
$(function(){
   console.log('Data with "data" ' + $('ul.country-list li.country:eq(1)').data('dial-code'));
   //OR
   console.log('Data with "attr" ' + $('ul.country-list li.country:eq(1)').attr('data-dial-code'));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul class="country-list">
        <li class="country preferred active" data-dial-code="1" data-country-code="us">
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="country-list">
        <li class="country preferred active" data-dial-code="48" data-country-code="pl">
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `.attr()` function as described in jQuery docs:

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

Just like this.Since you only need which is active `li` right?

```
var ddcode=$('.country-list .active').attr('data-dial-code');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need the second one with the class active

```
var value = $('ul.country-list li.active:eq(1)').data('dial-code');
```